# Regression with subsets and baseline specification + differing variables

Tags: r, regression

I want to regress a variable on a baseline specification and seven additional variables subsequently (i.e. 8 regressions). I want to do this for two subsets of the data.frame and for two subsets of the additional variables.

Then, I want to save the output of these 8x2x2=32 regressions grouped in `stargazer` by subset-combination (so 4 files). As you can imagine this is a huge typing effort. Some answers on SO are related to this (e.g. using `ddply` but I struggle with the combination, especially the fact that in every regression the baseline variables stay constant.

Here is the data where I reduce both the number of baseline variables (controls) and additional variables to two:

```
Two.Year <- 1:4
Length <- 4:8
NumAck <- 8:12
degree_max <- 15:19
degree_median <- 16:20
katz_max <- 19:23
katz_median <- 23:27
Year <- rep(c("early","late"), each=2)

Master <-as.data.frame(cbind(
 Two.Year, Length, NumAck, degree_max, degree_median, katz_max, katz_median, Year
 ))
```

The two subsets are defined by the levels in the variable Year.

The baseline regression is

```
lm(Two.Year ~ Length + NumAck,
  Data=subset(Master, subset=Publication.Year==early)
  )
```

The second and third are all the variables ending with `_max`, so `lm(Two.Year ~ Length + NumAck + degree_max, Data=Master)` and `lm(Two.Year ~ Length + NumAck + katz_max, Data=Master)`. This gives the second subset, defined as all the variables ending with `_max` and those ending with `_median`. So far I extract these with `grepl("_median", names(Master))` and `grepl("_max", names(Master))`.

As mentioned, I want to save the output of the subsets grouped. That is, all the regressions from (I) early and max, (II) early and median, (III) late and max and (IV) late and median.

So far I tried

```
Master.subset <- split(Master, Master$time)
ols <- ddply( Master[ Master$time %in% c('early','late'), ], "time",
  function(Master) coefficients(lm(Two.Year~., data=Master)))
```

and then save ols with `stargazer()`. From here I don't know how to select subsets of variables other than building real data frame subsets nor how to use baseline variables.

How do I do that? Any hint is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I finally did.

First I defined variables used for three loops:

```
# Write baseline model
baseline <- "Two.Year ~ Length + numAck"
# Write the model specific variables
measure <- c("degree", "katz")
# Write variable which determines the subset
timepoints <- c("early", "late")
```

The I contstructed three nested loops such that the variable subset, the data.frame subset and the formula subset are properly defined within the loops. At the end of the second loop I write the output to a file usinger `stargazer`.

```
# Output matrix
ols <- matrix()
# First loop for the time
for (tmpnt in considered_time) {
  # Estimate baseline model which is constant in tmpnt
  ols$baseline <- lm(as.formula(baseline),
    data=subset(Master, timepoint==tmpnt)
    )
  ols <- ols[-1] # for some reason the first column in ols is empty
  # Second loop for the variable subset
  for (type in c("median", "max", "mean")) {
    # Third loop for the estimation of all the other models
    for (msr in measures) {
      ols[[msr]] = lm(as.formula(paste(baseline, paste(msr, type, sep="_"), sep="+")),
        data=subset(Master, timepoint==tmpnt)
        )
      }
    # Write output to file
    stargazer(ols,
     title=paste("Regression output for ",tmpnt," subsample using ",type),    
     )
   }
 }
```